# Plugin options not overwritten when existing in pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, mojo

Working on a maven plugin for bringing the C / C++ world to Maven (based on Mark Donzelmann's nar-maven-plugin ), I came into the following situation:
When specifying options to my plugin in the pom.xml of another project using it, I can't overwrite them by command line.
The maven commands I am using are standard and the mojo is attached to the lifecycle.
So I am not directly calling my plugin. Any ideas?
Example:

```
 /**
 * location of other documentation of this project 
 * 
 * @parameter property="gnu.build.make.args" default-value=""
 */
private String makeArgs;
```

**pom.xml:
  <makeArgs>PLATFORM=android</makeArgs>**

invocation:
   mvn clean compile install -Dgnu.build.make.args=PLATFORM\=android

Leaving out the part in the pom.xml does make the command line option pass through.